# PDF manual of ASUS GTX 295

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, documentation

I am unable to find and download the user's manual for this GFX card by ASUS:
ENGTX295/2DI/1792MD3 (it's the non-OCed version of GeForce GTX 295)

Where is it hidden?

Comment: Wow.  Good question.  You'd think they'd make that easy. Their documentation is spotty at best, mostly non-existent.

Comment: I never had problem to get PDF manuals for other ASUS products, (specially motherboards) and this is something I didn't expect from ASUS at this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to undig the original package of my GFX card.

It appears that it had 3 pieces of information:

- A CD with PDF documantation in many languages about the use of software/drivers
- A printed guide about hardware installation for a GFX card, without specific details about the model
- A leaflet of how to connect the included SPDIF cable so you can have sound output to the digital ports at the back of the GFX card (and that was what I was searching for!)

Now I know why there is nothing at the download page:
All info is general about all models.